# How to use a constants in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, constants, vue-component, vuex

A VueJS project:
I have a form object, where each property is bind with a corresponding form input.
The object inside of the components looks like:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        isbn: '',
        title: '',
        author: '',
        description: '',
        creationDate: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {            
    onReset (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault(); 
      /* Reset our form values */
      this.form = {
        isbn: '',
        title: '',
        author: '',
        description: '',
        creationDate: ''
    }; 
    ...
}
```

Since I'm repeating myself, I want to define a constant (with default values) and then to use it in the above sections, like:

```
const DEFAULT_FORM_STATE = {
  isbn: '',
  title: '',
  author: '',
  description: '',
  creationDate: ''
};

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      form: DEFAULT_FORM_STATE
    }
  },
  methods: {            
    onReset (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault(); 
      /* Reset our form values */
      this.form = DEFAULT_FORM_STATE; 
    ...
}
```

But for some reason this is not working.
One of the options that I tried was with plugins:

I have a new **constants.js** file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const CustomConsts = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        const CONSTS = {
            DEFAULT_FORM_STATE: {
                isbn: '',
                title: '',
                author: '',
                description: '',
                creationDate: ''
            }
        }
        Vue.prototype.$getConst = (key) => {
            return CONSTS[key]
        }
    }
};

export default CustomConsts;
```

which I then included in **main.js** file:

```
...
import CustomConsts from './constants'

Vue.use(CustomConsts);
... 
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

and later tried to use it back in my component like:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      form: this.$getConst('DEFAULT_FORM_STATE')
    }
  },
  methods: {            
    onReset (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault(); 
      /* Reset our form values */
        this.form = this.$getConst('DEFAULT_FORM_STATE'); 
 ...
  }
```

I also tried without `this.` prefix.

But none of it is not working. I don't have to use a plugin if this is not the good idea. I need any idea which can be used for replacing the whole object (which now I have in both places) with a single constant with default values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `Object.assign` to make a copy each time.

You should be returning a new object for each Vue component instance anyway, otherwise all components will share the same object.

```
const DEFAULT_FORM_STATE = {
 isbn: '',
 title: '',
 author: '',
 description: '',
 creationDate: ''
};

export default {
  data () {
   return {
    form: Object.assign({},DEFAULT_FORM_STATE)
  }
},
methods: {            
 onReset (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); 
  /* Reset our form values */
  this.form = Object.assign({},DEFAULT_FORM_STATE); 
...
}
```

Notice the **`Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_FORM_STATE)`** parts.

Comment: You could simplify `Object.asign()` with `{...DEFAULT_FORM_STATE}`